# EGit: Merge without a commit

Tags: egit

Is it possible to merge a branch without a commit like it would be possible with C git `git merge myBranch --no-ff --no-commit`?

Repository settings like `merge.ff = no` or `merge.commit = no` are ignored.

I'm using EGit 3.0 which comes with the new Kepler release of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now available in EGit 3.1 and later.

Answer (score 2):

The merge options are available in the merge dialog which can be invoked like this:

1. Select a project
2. Open its context menu, select *Team* > *Merge...*
3. Chose the branch to merge and the desired options below

Note that currently only squashing and fast-forward options are supported.

Comment: Bug ticket https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=335091 suggests that a --no-commit option has been added. I just cant find it :P

Comment: That comment was about JGit (it's not clear, but I checked). I opened [bug 411978](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=411978) for adding the option to the merge dialog. By the way, if you want to make further adjustments to the merge commit afterwards, an alternative would be to ammend it, which works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is! You have to use `git rebase`. This blog post explains how to do it: http://www.kerrybuckley.org/2008/06/18/avoiding-merge-commits-in-git/

Comment: Rebase is something different. I want a merge. The changelog of EGit said it would be included in 3.0.

Comment: @T3rm1: Where did you see that `--no-commit` is supported in EGit?

Comment: @T3rm1: Nope, you rebase your branch on top of master. Then, when you merge into master, git will not generate a merge commit.

Comment: @robinst Take a look at this bug ticket: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=335091

Comment: @user1158559 I know that. It won't create a merge commit because it will be a fast forward. But that's really not what I want. `git merge --no-ff --no-commit` does something different.